# put retrieved image from coredata to array swift

Tags: arrays, image, swift, core-data

I want to put the retrieved image from CoreData to my [UImage] Array but actually this one gave me this error: Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.Image' (0x7fb4baea09d0) to 'UIImage' (0x10c180758).

Here is the code:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ImageVen")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        let result:NSArray = try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        if result.count > 0 {
            for picture in result {
                let immagin = picture as! UIImage
                self.immaginiArrayVenerdi.append(immagin)
            }
        }
```

How can i solve this error? Thank you!

Comment: some ideas to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
let result:NSArray = try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)
```

That means `result` will be an array of `NSManagedObject`. But then you do this:

```
        for picture in result {
            let immagin = picture as! UIImage
            self.immaginiArrayVenerdi.append(immagin)
        }
```

You can't just use `as!` to convert from `NSManagedObject` to `UIImage`, because they're completely different classes, not even similar to each other. If your entity `ImageVen` has a property which is a `UIImage`, you could use the value of that property. But you can't just tell the compiler to make that conversion, because `as!` doesn't give it enough information to know how.